# Changing from Play to Pause after Set is clicked

Tags: javascript

How would I set this up so that the button changes from play to pause after '**Set**' is clicked.

Pressing '**Set**' would trigger the svg to change to the pause button.

**Code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/192h0w85/195/

```
    (function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const player = document.getElementById("player");
    const button = document.getElementById("button");
    const value = document.getElementById("input");
    const sent = document.getElementById("sent");
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle('is-playing')
        if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
        } else {
            player.pause();
        }
    });
    sent.addEventListener("click", function() {
        player.volume = 1.0;
        player.src = value.value;
    });
}());
```

Comment: But what is "Set"?

Comment: It's in the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/192h0w85/195/

Comment: You could just add `button.classList.toggle('is-playing');` to your `sent` click event handler. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Should I change the first one to button too, instead of this? Changing 'this' to 'button' this.classList.toggle('is-playing')

Comment: Either works, as `this` in that context references the button element. @MichelleSmith

Comment: What if I don't want it to flip back to the Play button, only Pause, When set is pressed? How would that be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have button click event added

You can just trigger that click to have a changed icons

So, your code will look like this

```
(function iife() {
  "use strict";
  const player = document.getElementById("player");
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  const value = document.getElementById("input");
  const sent = document.getElementById("sent");

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('is-playing')
    if (player.paused) {
      player.play();
    } else {
      player.pause();

    }
  });

  sent.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.volume = 1.0;
    player.src = value.value;
    button.click();
  });
}());
```

Note:  `button.click();`

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";
  const player = document.getElementById("player");
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  const value = document.getElementById("input");
  const sent = document.getElementById("sent");

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('is-playing')
    if (player.paused) {
      player.play();
    } else {
      player.pause();

    }
  });

  sent.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.volume = 1.0;
    player.src = value.value;
    button.click();
  });
}());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn .play,
.btn .pause {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.play {
  fill: #000000;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.play path {
  fill: blue;
}

.pause {
  fill: #000000;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.pause path {
  fill: blue;
}

.pause {
  display: none;
}

.is-playing .play {
  display: none;
}

.is-playing .pause {
  display: block;
}

.label {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}

.info {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.input {
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: black;
  color: blue;
}

.sent {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: black;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<audio autoplay id="player"></audio>


<div id="button" class="btn">
  <svg class="play hide" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 24 24">

<circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12"> </circle>
<path d="M9.846 16.86c-.467.303-.846.097-.846-.45V7.588c0-.551.38-.752.846-.45l6.91 4.48c.324.21.327.549 0 .761l-6.91 4.48z">
    </path></svg>
  <svg class="pause" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12"> </circle>

<path d="M8 7.596c0-.33.277-.596.607-.596h1.786c.335 0 .607.267.607.596v8.808a.605.605 0 0 1-.607.596H8.607A.602.602 0 0 1 8 16.404V7.596zm5 0c0-.33.277-.596.607-.596h1.786c.335 0 .607.267.607.596v8.808a.605.605 0 0 1-.607.596h-1.786a.602.602 0 0 1-.607-.596V7.596z">
    </path></svg>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <label class="label" for="input">Text</label>
  <input class="input" id="input" type="text" name="someNameHere" value="http://hi5.1980s.fm/;" />
  <input class="sent" id="sent" type="submit" value="Set" />
</div>
```

Comment: @MichelleSmith you can its up to you, I added trigger solution because I do not have to write the same code again, you can write toggle class or create common function to do this work for you.

Comment: What if I don't want it to flip back to the Play button, only Pause, When set is pressed? How would that be written?

Comment: @MichelleSmith in that case the best I can advice is to create function that accepts arguments with play pause and you pass it to function from your clicks and function will do the work for you.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with what you suggested in it please? https://jsfiddle.net/192h0w85/203/

Comment: Was there a specific reason why you changed 'button' back to 'this'?  this.classList.toggle('is-playing')

Comment: @MichelleSmith you do not need new keyword, everything else looks good to me

Comment: jslint told me it was needed.

Comment: Fixed. I changed it to this instead: playPauseIcon / Now jslint isn't telling me to add 'new' / And thank you for your help, greatly appreciated. https://jsfiddle.net/192h0w85/219/